# Studying extreme value r.v. $X=\max_i (c_i+X_i)$ where $c_i$ are constants and $X_i$ are i.i.d. r.v

Tags: distributions, random-variable, independence, iid

Let
$X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be independently and identically distributed random variables  according to a distribution $F$.

There are constants: $c_1,c_2,...,c_n$.

Define a new random variable $X=\max_i(X_i+c_i)$.

Is it possible to derive the distribution of $X$ in terms of $F$ and all $c_i$? Based on the derivation, when would $X$ also have the distribution $F$?

Comment: You are looking for *extreme value statistics*. Here is a comprehensive introduction: https://doi.org/10.3389/fphy.2020.604053

Comment: @cdalitz So those three distributions are the only distributions that solves my second problem?

Comment: Your statement is inconsistent: when all the $X_i$ have a common distribution $F,$ necessarily they have *identical means.*  Please clarify your question.

Comment: Re the edit: please explain what you mean by "same shape:" this has several possible reasonable interpretations in this context.  Note that regardless how you specify your question, *of course* it's possible to find the distribution of $X,$ because it is completely determined by the distributions of the $X_i.$  BTW, you still ask us to suppose these are "identically distributed" variables!

Comment: @whuber I had a misunderstanding that i.i.d. rv can have different means. Hopefully now it is clarified.

Comment: There is no general formula; but your final question might be of some interest due to its relation to the limit theorems in extreme value theory. (+1)  For instance, when $F$ is a standard Gumbel distribution and every $x_i = -\log(n),$ then $X$ again has $F$ for its distribution.

Comment: @whuber Is it possible to prove that no general formula exists?

Comment: Sure.  I invite you to work out a formula even for the case $n=2:$ you will quickly see what's happening.  A general formula would involve $O(n!)$ integrals corresponding to all possible reorderings of the $x_i.$

Comment: @whuber Yes indeed you are right: the formula is messy. The distributions are iid though, does it help to reduce thermula a bit?

Comment: One would hope the *iid* condition would help, but whether it does will depend on the particulars of $F.$  There isn't any general simplification arising from that assumption.

Answer (score 1):

In my notation $X_i \sim f$ with CDF $F$. If $X$ is the maximum of $n$ draws, it means that one sample lies at $X$ and the other $n-1$ must lie below it. Thus we have
$$
p(X) = n \cdot f(X) \cdot F(X)^{n-1}
$$
The factors here are i) a combinatiorial factor for the fact that any of the draws could have been the maximum one, ii) a factor for one sample at $X$, iii) a factor for $n - 1$ samples below $X$, written using the CDF.

Now, suppose we want for all $X$
$$
p(X) = f(X) = n \cdot f(X) \cdot F(X)^{n-1}
$$
then we evidently require that for all $X$
$$
n F(X)^{n-1} = 1
$$
which isn't possible enless $n=1$.

Comment: Hi, in your first formula, did you assume that the mean of $X_i$ are all the same or not?

Comment: There's no need to assume $F$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @dodo, yes the X_i are iid draws from distribution f

Comment: @whuber you’re quite right, thanks

Comment: In your notation, my original question wants to derive the distribution of $X$ using the distribution of $X_i$. They are not necessarily the same distribution. However, you seem to assume that $X$ and $X_i$ have the same distribution.